# Make div to strech in height between another divs, if overflow then scroll

Tags: css, html, scroll, position

I have a css problem like this:

I have 3 divs, imagine they're all stacked in a column (like table with 3 rows) and the top one and the bottom one has `height: 100px;` and `position: absolute;` for example and they're like header and footer, they always stick to the top and the bottom of my form.

The height of the whole form can vary depending on other elements in the form, so I need my middle div to be just between the other 2 divs, and if it doesn't fit with it's content, to scroll.

(For example header and footer are `100px` height, the form is just `500px` height and the text in middle div is very very long) <- at the moment the middle div expands and streches the whole form.

I've tried many things to solve this with positioning, marging, padding of the elements, but still no success... Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll be waiting to include some code and maybe a working example. Explaining this with just text is no mean feet :)

Comment: wait a minute, i'll create a fiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n8sZ7/11/

Comment: Try making the middle div `height:100%;` and `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way: <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/n8sZ7/24/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
.header, .footer {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.form {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just a little bit of JS as simple as this?

```
var form_height=300, footer_height=100, header_height=100;

document.getElementById('content').style.height=form_height - header_height - footer_height +'px';
```

Just adding that your code works:

http://jsfiddle.net/n8sZ7/23/

HTML

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header, .footer {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}

.form {
    height: 300px; 
}

.content {
    overflow-y: scroll; <!-- I want this to fit between header and footer (in this example to get 100px of height) without using any javascript -->
}
```